# Prove extension is not Galois

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity

I believe the extension $\mathbb Q(16^{\frac{1}{3}}):\mathbb Q$ is not Galois, and I'm trying to prove why. Is it enough to say that $16^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is a root of the polynomial $x^3-16$ over $\mathbb Q$ but it also contains complex roots, thus $\mathbb Q(16^{\frac{1}{3}})$ does not contain all the algebraic conjugates of $16^{\frac{1}{3}}$ so is not a Galois extension of $\mathbb Q$?

Is this correct? If so, is there a neater way to say this?

Comment: It is very close to being complete and correct. You also need to observe that $x^3-16$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$. But I'm sure you can manage that with the aid of the rational root test :-) Lord Shark opted to use another generating element, where irreducibility of the relevant polynomial is immediate by Eisenstein. That is, of course, also correct (and brings up a useful way of viewing this extension field differently).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually $\Bbb Q(16^{1/3})=\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})$. A Galois extension of $\Bbb Q$
must contain all conjugates of any of its elements over $\Bbb Q$.
One of the conjugates of $2^{1/3}$ is $2^{1/3}\exp(2\pi i/3)$ which is
not real, and so cannot lie in $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})$.